# Source /opt/nvm/nvm.sh via Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, docker-compose, nvm

I have a `Dockerfile`. Current user is `root`. The script sets `NVM_DIR` to `/opt/nvm`. The script installs NVM (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) via the `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash` command. I set the entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]` and the command to `CMD ["start"]`.

I then attempt to start this via Docker Compose. Now since the NVM installer script adds the following code to the `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc` files.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

As you can see `NVM_DIR` is set to `"$HOME/.nvm"` which in our case is incorrect since I installed NVM to `/opt/nvm`. So I set the `NVM_DIR` variable in the Docker Compose file:

```
environment:
  - NVM_DIR=/opt/nvm
```

I am however aware that this is a non-interactive shell. This doesn't work though. I suspect that the NVM is not being sourced by the non-interactive shell.

How does one source the `/opt/nvm/nvm.sh` file when running a Docker image via Docker Compose?

Comment: When you reset `NVM_DIR` in the script, it does not matter how you set it in the environment.